# Dojo1.8: I am not able to update label of each Button instance while creating instances from Button

Tags: dojo

I am not able to update label of each Button instance while creating instances from button.
How do I work around it? Or can I not code it as follows?

```
registry.byId(new Obj_Button({
   id:'star'+ i,
   label:'Button '+ i, //it will not work, so how to solve it???
}).placeAt(dom.byId('new1')));
```

Also please see my jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/clementyap/sTxbh/42/

regards 
Clement

Comment: Why not have your custom button extend the `dijit/form/Button` widget instead of `_WidgetBase`? Then you will have access to all of its properties and methods, so setting a label on your custom button would work exactly as if you were creating a new `dijit/form/Button`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your widget needs to be coded to handle `label`

```
declare("Obj_Button", [_WidgetBase], {

        postMixInProperties: function() {
          if(!this.label)
              this.label = 'New Button Instance';
        },

        buildRendering: function () {
            // create the DOM for this widget
            this.domNode = domConstruct.create("button", {
                innerHTML: this.label
            });
        }
    });
```

Also, you can just instantiate the widget, the `registry.byId` call is not needed.

Comment: Hi Craig, Thank you for your help. In that case how do I instantiate the widget in order for the widget to be created and destroyed after the page is loaded completely? I could not find any help that can instantiate widget, other than by registry.byId?

Comment: registry.byId is to retrieve an existing widget by an id.  Any widget that uses _WidgetBase, which should be most, will automatically add itself to the registry when it is instantiated.